# Getting this error "com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException: Internal error has occurred when executing Firebase ML tasks"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

> Getting FirebaseMLException in onFailure: Internal error has occurred when executing Firebase ML tasks.

```
    FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions options =
            new FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder()
                    .setBarcodeFormats(
                            FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE,
                            FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_AZTEC)
                    .build();

    FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);


    FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
            .getVisionBarcodeDetector();



    Task<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>> result = detector.detectInImage(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionBarcode> barcodes) {
                    getInfoFromBarCodes(barcodes);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    // Task failed with an exception
                    Toast.makeText(BarCodeDetectionActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

## Manifest

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.ml.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="face,barcode" />
```

Comment: Can you please paste the full stack trace?

Comment: Got it resolved by converting bitmap to Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888!!!

Comment: Cool. Can you please post an update to your question with your finding? or you can post an answer yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Here i got it resolved by converting bitmap to Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 earlier which is Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

```
 FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Why this is the solution and how have got to this?